# How to ensure that no duplicate records created using LINQ to SQL in multi-threading applications?

Tags: linq-to-sql

Creating the records follows a simple flow: check if there is no similar record in the DB, and if not, create a record.  The seriesInstUid is not the primary key.  The primary key is created by SQL server as it has the identity property setup on server.

Like code below:

```
            DataClassAsclepiusImagingDataContext db = new DataClassAsclepiusImagingDataContext();
            var matchingSeries = from s in db.Series
                                 where s.DDSeriesInstanceUID == dd.seriesInsUid
                                 select s;

            if ((matchingSeries == null) || (matchingSeries.Count() < 1))
            {
                Series ser = new Series();

                db.GetTable<Series>().InsertOnSubmit(ser);
                db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

The problem occures when a few concurent threads trying to execute the same code in a rapid succession, a record may be created by another caller in between the "if record exists?" and "if not create new record".  In such case the first caller would create a duplicate.

What is a good way to ensure that the duplicates are not created in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are couple of ways to do it.
1) You can add a unique constraint on the database to be absolutely sure that no duplicates can be created.
2) Encapsulate the data insert code within the lock block to ensure that only one thread can execute the insert at a time.

Comment: the # 1 seems to be useful: can you ellaborate on the unique constraint?  I am using SQL Server 2005.  The only one fied must be unique and it's not the primary key.  Thanks.

Comment: The field does not have to be primary key. If you just want it to be unique, you can create a unique contraint by running a query like:
alter table Series add constraint [UN_Series_1] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
 [DDSeriesInstanceUID] ASC
) ON [PRIMARY]

You can also do it from SQL Server Management Studio by right-clicking on table, selecting Design, right-clicking column, selecting Index/Relationship and then creating a new key of type Unique Key.

If you want to do additional validation during insert/update, you can use a trigger:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Comment: The columns are of nvarchar[MAX] type. I don't think I can set them to unique constraint, or do I?  The criteria for the new record creation is only if no record with ALL the fields are the same.  Any Ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: the max size is 900 bytes so if it is nvarchar[MAX], it won't work. However, you can use the trigger (link above) for the purpose. It will execute the code each time a row is inserted or updated. You can do whatever needs to be validated and rollback if it violates a condition you want to enforce.

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER db.EnsureUnique ON db.Series
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
 IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM db.Series s INNER JOIN inserted AS i 
  ON s.DDSeriesInstanceUID = i.DDSeriesInstanceUID AND
   [all other fields]
          )
 BEGIN
  RAISERROR ('The record already exists.', 16, 1);
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
 RETURN 
END;